# what are the minimum dimensions for xxlarge and xxxlarge screen in terms of dp?

Tags: android, screen-size

xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp. But the dimensions for larger screen size have not been given on [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). What type of devices have xxlarge and xxxlarge screens?

Comment: Where are you seeing that xxlarge and xxxlarge are actual screen sizes?

Comment: There are `xxhdpi` and `xxxhdpi` densities, but I am not aware of such sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a table from a [Pro Android Graphics by Wallace Jackson](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=wZ8QAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA126&lpg=PA126&dq=xxxhdpi%20vs%20xxlarge&source=bl&ots=nDPjW93NVW&sig=Tv2VdlETDbC400rCKe9IMZnRCDw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig9uH0rObLAhWLGI4KHfpCAmgQ6AEIRTAG#v=onepage&q&f=false). Apparently it's same as xxhdpi and xxxhdpi respectively.

[image]